# Adding Mollie payments to spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, payment, spree, mollie

I'm currently building an webshop that's based in The Netherlands.

[iDEAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEAL) is the most used online payment platform in The Netherlands and I'm trying to add this payment platform to my app. The only problem is that all current gems that support iDEAL (providers) are a couple of years old and don't work anymore with the most recent version of Spree

I've started doing **research** on how to add this to my app:

I've tried [asking](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-ruby/issues/69) the developers of the official [Ruby on Rails Mollie gem](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-ruby)  to help me create an version for Spree. Even though they couldn't help me create an version for spree, they did try to send me into the right direction.

Advising me to read the [documentation](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/payments.html#adding-your-custom-gateway) and reading through the code of the following gems and use them as an example

- [Example gateway](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero)
- [Spree Mollie gem (8 years old)](https://github.com/pero-ict-solutions/spree-mollie-ideal)
- [Spree Mollie gem (4 years old)](https://github.com/javereec/spree_mollie)
- [Spree Mollie gem (2 years old)](https://github.com/ttcremers/spree_mollie)
- [Spree Mollie gem (11 months old)](https://github.com/RostislavKorin/spree_mollie)

I've looked at al the gems, read through the code, read the documentation and even tried this [tutorial](https://www.madetech.com/blog/spree-custom-gateway).

**My attempts:**
When I try to install the most recent [gem](https://github.com/RostislavKorin/spree_mollie) (after `bundle install`) with the following code `bundle exec rails g spree_mollie:install`

I get the following error:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 14008
      append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js
      append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js
      insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
      insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css
         run  bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations FROM=spree_mollie from "."
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'railties:install:migrations' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Would you like to run the migrations now? [Y/n] y
         run  bundle exec rake db:migrate from "."
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried looking for the cause of the problem, but couldn't find an answer it appears the rake command `rake db:migrate` can't be found nor can `ailties:install:migrations`

which I think causes the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Spree::Admin::PaymentMethods#index
```

as it can't seem to find: `couldn't find file 'spree/backend/spree_mollie' with type 'text/css'`

citing that `*= require spree/backend/spree_mollie` is the cause of the problem

**error**:

`*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require spree/backend/spree_mollie
*/`

I'm desperately trying to get the gem to work. I've tried creating my own [gem](https://github.com/salman15/mollie_spreee) (build from the others), but the results are the same.

**GOAL**: I'm trying to get add Mollie to my Spree app

**PROBLEM**: all current gems are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working at Mollie and responsible for our Spree Commerce module. We launched our official Spree Mollie Gateway a few months ago: https://github.com/mollie/spree-mollie-gateway

Comment: I've started using it since it's been released. Thank you for making such a great gem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I'm running Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0 and Spree 3.1.12

I used the [Spree Mollie gem (2 years old)](https://github.com/ttcremers/spree_mollie) gem and downgraded the [Ruby on Rails Mollie](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-ruby) gem to the required version. After creating a Mollie account I inserted the `test_api_key` and Mollie worked